# Django url pattern is not detected in js file

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I'm using `main.js` file for java script logic in Django project. When i'm writing this logic inside script tag in `base.html`, it's working as expected. But, if I separate the logic in `.js` file, i'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%` by pointing `url : {% url 'like-post' %},` in browser console.

base.html:

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'blog/main.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Blog</title>

</head>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pk = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : {% url 'like-post' %},
            data : {'id' : pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(response){
                $(".like-section").load(" .like-section")
                   
            },
            error : function(rs, e){
                console.log(rs.responseText); 
            },
        });
    });
});
```

I have few other js logic in `main.js` file, it's working as expected if i comment out above portion in `main.js` file.

Comment: javascript files arent rendered by django so you can't use django template language in them.

Comment: Ok..Is there any better workaround to handle this logic?

Answer (score 0):

create another folder and name that as "static". Inside that paste the .js file.
Then in base.html file, {% load static %}. You are all done.